# Angular 4 pass data on router navigate

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible to pass data to component using `router.navigate` when I have `Route` like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'photos',  component: PhotosComponent},
  { path: 'create-album', component: CreateAlbumComponent, data: {sameVar: 'value'}}
];
```

I am looking for something like

```
router.navigate(['create-album'], myDataObj);
```

Comment: Is having the data show in url a possibility?

Comment: I don't want to do that

Comment: Okay, then a shared service is what you need.

Comment: That is what I have now ... but i though that this also could be the way

Comment: No not really, if you need to share data between components and not affect the url in anyway, then you want a shared service.